SQL Shell (psql) Defaulting to Port 5433 Instead of 5432 on Windows
I am running PostgreSQL on Windows, and my PostgreSQL server is correctly configured to use port 5432. However, when I open the SQL Shell (psql), it defaults to port 5433, as shown in the screenshot below:default value is 5433
Steps I Took to Resolve:

Verified the postgresql.conf file located at C:\Program
Files\PostgreSQL\17\data\postgresql.conf and confirmed that port =
5432.

Restarted the PostgreSQL service using net stop postgresql-x64-17
and net start postgresql-x64-17.

Updated the pg_env.bat file located at C:\Program
Files\PostgreSQL\17\pg_env.bat by changing the port variable to
5432. Restarted the computer after
this.

Verified that the PGPORT environment variable wasn’t
explicitly defined

Used SHOW port; within psql, and it correctly
displays 5432 as the active server port.


Despite these steps, SQL Shell (psql) still defaults to 5433 when prompting for the port. How can I make it default to 5432 permanently?

Change your environment settings for the psql client application. You (or somebody else) did this before, since  5433 is not the default value. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-ENVIRONMENT

To question text add the following information: 1) You installed using EDB installer correct? 2) Have you installed more then one version/instance of Postgres?

This is controlled by:
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQl\17\scripts\runpsql.bat
Specifically this:
SET port=5433
SET /P port="Port [%port%]: "

At some point this file was configured during the Postgresql install to point at 5433.
Edit the file to:
SET port=5432

There are two possibilities:

You have the environment variable PGPORT set to 5433. Remove that environment variable, and the PostgreSQL client library libpq will connect to port 5432 by default.

Your PostgreSQL was configured to default to port 5433 when it was built from source. That would mean that you are using a custom build of PostgreSQL, because the publicly available binaries are not built like that.



Pretty sure the OP is using the EDB installer and that will assign different port numbers if you are running more then one instance of Postgres on a machine, much like the Debian/Ubuntu and RH packages. My guess we are seeing the leftovers of a incomplete install or uninstall.

@AdrianKlaver Probably, but how else should that affect the default port the client uses?

Not quite sure what you are getting at. SQL Shell is basically a  shell script that wraps  psql, I have not looked close enough at how it picks up the port to suggest as the default, but if I remember correctly it will pick up the last port assigned.

@AdrianKlaver Ah, okay. I have no access to Windows. Then my answer may be off the mark.

I cranked up a Windows instance on a dual boot machine and found the shell script that runs SQL Shell. See my answer for more detail.

Set the PGPORT Environment Variable
setx PGPORT 5432 /M and export PGPORT=5432

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

You probably have a previous version of Postgres installed.  Uninstall it and ensure that 5432 is free.  Check Windows Services to ensure no other old version is running.  Also check netstat to ensure something else is not on that port.  Then reinstall it.  Postgres will automatically go to the next port up for another installation that is present on the default 5432.

This has nothing to do with the PostgreSQL database. The problem is the psql client. Somebody or something changed the default settings. Change it back and you're fine. You don't have to reinstall the database server for this.

Read the question again, the active Postgres server is running on port 5432. The issue is that SQL Shell which is a wrapper around psql is picking up some previous port value of 5433  that is stored somewhere and using that as the suggested/default port to connect as. It is entirely possible for the OP to override that value by typing in 5432 and connect to the Postgres instance.

I'm assuming this was installed via the Win installer and the OP installed the server and client both. It seems likely that the OP installed PG and then installed a newer server or client and was using the newer client against the older server or something of that ilk, which gives this result easily.  Would just changing a port in a client wrapper script may be a band aid rather than a cure @FrankHeikens ?

I also assume the OP didn't do a custom build if they were struggling to figure out the client connect vs listening port - on Windows @Adrian Klaver.

From question Used SHOW port; within psql, and it correctly displays 5432 as the active server port. established that the server that the OP wanted to connect was up and running on 5432.  Reinstalling was not: 1) Going to change that. 2) Totally unnecessary. I know in the WIndows world repeatedly reinstalling is associated with magic that cures all, but in the real world one identifies the actual issue and solves that.
